# How to put the value of multiple cells in another sheet from a reference code

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

this is the problem: I have two worksheets, one that records and discriminates revenues and expenses:

[image]

And other that contains a table with the price, revenue and taxes for each product:

[image]

Now, I need function that receives the code (or the description name) of a product on the first worksheet and put the values ​​(income, taxes, price) available in the second worksheet, this way:
[image]

I thought of such a solution, but it gives me a parsing error:
[image]

So if you can share a little of your intelligence and mental power with me, I'll be  grateful until the nex [aeon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeon#Astronomy_.26_Cosmology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `=VLOOKUP(B4,tax_table!A:F,2,FALSE)` ?

Comment: Thanks, @pnuts , Now I'm going to research how make the product code from the other sheet autocomplete.

Comment: I've already implement fill 'DESCRIPTION' based com 'PRODUCT_COD' (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891387/google-script-function-that-insert-new-row-copying-functions-formulas-from-last) But I'd like to type the first letter of the code and have all codes with that letter shown (real codes have letters, not numbers like the sample in the question). Thanks again!